# PHP - Parse text file for certain patterns

Tags: php

I got a text file and a certain text pattern. I would like to parse the text file and create files out of it. How do I recognize the pattern?

Pattern

```
##Headline1
# Lorem Ipsum, lorem ipsum....
##Headline2
# Lorem Ipsum, lorem ipsum....
##Headline3
# Lorem Ipsum, lorem ipsum....
##Headline4
# Lorem Ipsum, lorem ipsum....
```

Files

```
   headline1.php
   headline2.php
   headline3.php
    .....
```

Single File

```
  <h1>Headline1</h1>
  <p> Lorem ipsum....</p>
```

Comment: 1) So you want the script to automatically detect a pattern in your file? 2) Have you tried something and started with some code?

Comment: unclear, create file out of it ? little more detail please.

Comment: @Jigar want to create .php files out of it, I added some details above

Comment: @vuvu means `##` for `<h1>` and `#` for `<p>`, always ?

Comment: @Jigar yes, how can I achieve that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a search for the "##" using [explode() function][1]   [1]: http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php

```
$file = file_gets_content('file1.txt');
$headlines = explode('##', $file);
foeach($headlines as $headline){
}
```

And then keep coding yourself!

Comment: Thank you, but actually I meant to structure the new file in headline and paragraph, i updated my question

Comment: Ohh thats very simple just use str_replace('#' ,'</p><h1>', $yourString); 
then search  str_replace('#' ,'</h1><p>', $yourString); and then use substr to delete the first </p> 
$yourString  = substr($yourString , 4);